# Using react phone input 2 with pre-existing phone numbers is assuming wrong area code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, internationalization

So we have tons of phone numbers pre-existing in our db and are trying to switch over to use the react-phone-input-2 component.

The problem is, most of our phone numbers, if not all, are saved without country codes. So when placing this component into our code, it's assuming the first 1 or 2 digits as a country code when it shouldn't be.

Let's say my phone number was saved previously such as: 8161234567

This should be an American number, but clearly there isn't a country code saved with it. When I place the component in our code, it appears like so:
[image]

instead of what I would like to happen:
[image]

Our component is implemented like so:

```
interface PhoneNumberInput2Props {
  name: string;
  value: string;
  onChange: (value: any, country: any, e: any, formattedValue: any) => void;
  id?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  placeholder?: string;
  label?: string;
  country?: string;
}
const PhoneNumberInput2 = (props: PhoneNumberInput2Props) => {
  const {
    name,
    value,
    onChange,
    id = "phoneInput",
    disabled = false,
    placeholder,
    label,
    country
  } = props;

  return (
    <Wrapper>
      {label && <FormLabel htmlFor={id}>{label}</FormLabel>}
      <PhoneInput
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        inputProps={{
          id: id,
          name: name,
          autoComplete: "off"
        }}
        country={country ?? "us"}
        preferredCountries={["us", "ca"]}
        disabled={disabled}
        placeholder={placeholder}
        buttonStyle={{
          backgroundColor: "#EEEEEE",
          border: "1px solid #d3d3d3"
        }}
        inputStyle={{
          borderRadius: "3px",
          height: "44px",
          width: "100%"
        }}
        copyNumbersOnly={false}
        enableSearch={true}
        disableSearchIcon={true}
      />
    </Wrapper>
  );
};
```

and when I use it anywhere, it's used like so:

```
                      <PhoneNumberInput2
                        disabled={!hasAccess}
                        id={"contact-phone-input"}
                        name={"phone_number"}
                        value={
                          values?.phone_number &&
                          values?.phone_number?.toString()
                        }
                        onChange={formattedValue => {
                          setFieldValue("phone_number", formattedValue);
                        }}
                        placeholder={"Enter a phone number (optional)"}
                      />
```

Essentially, I'm curious if there is a way to default to a particular country and "fill in" the area code if it doesn't exist, or if there may be a better workaround for this I'm not considering?

Comment: did you find a solution to this?